# Add facebook comments inside a 'lightbox'

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, comments

I am building a website to showcase some photos. The photos are viewed using a lightbox like effect. I want to add facebook comments inside the 'lightbox' but the comments doesn't load.

$(function() {

```
    $('.pics').click(function(){

         ...
         ...

         $(".comments").html("<div id=\"fb-root\"></div><script src=\"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1\">" + "<" + "/" + "script>" + "<fb:comments href=\"example.com\" num_posts=\"5\" width=\"800\"></fb:comments>");

          }); 

    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try rendering the comments first but keep them invisible.  Something like:

```
<div id="comments" class="hidden">      
  <fb:comments href="example.com" num_posts="5" width="800"></fb:comments>
</div>
```

Assume the hidden class makes the `div` invisible.

Now with JavaScript code you should be able to do this:

```
$(".pics").click(function(){
    $("#comments").show();
});
```

I have not tested this yet and there's an off-chance Facebook won't load the comments into an invisible element.  If that's the case, you might be able to get away with rendering it and adding the `hidden` class after the page loads, though there might be a flicker.

Comment: thanks for your help. It works perfectly.
But I've come up with something different... you see when I add 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script> only in the head tag then the comments don't load. But when I add the script to both the head tag and inside the 'lightbox' function(as shown in the question) then it works! I don't konw why though.

Comment: Are you still writing the `<script/>` tag via document.write()?

Comment: I'm including `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>` in the `<head>` section of html. And I am also writing the same `<script/>` using `jquery.html()` when I make the lightbox call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this one http://www.zemgo.net23.net/lightbox.html