# How to add facebook comments in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I want to add facebook comments inside the 'lightbox' but the comments doesn't load..i dnt understand whats happening with this code..if i place that code over a any php file then it works but when i place the code inside my lighbox function using jQuery,comments doesn't load..plz suggest something.. Here is my code.

```
fununction show_image(){
var div_comments = jQuery("<div style=\"float:right;\"></div>")
            jQuery("#lightbox").append(div_comments);
var fbcomments = jQuery("<div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"http://example.com/comments\" data-numposts=\"5\"></div>");
            div_comments.append(fbcomments);   }
```

on click event of image, show_image() called.
i called the function for loading facebook comments in ready function..here is the function for loading facebook comments..

```
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

plz tell me where m wrong

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179569/add-facebook-comments-inside-a-lightbox?rq=1

Comment: i already used that method... not works for me

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you solved this or not anf frankly, I'm not sure what you mean by "comments doesn't load". There's two things you could mean:

1) The actual comment box doesn't load... as in, it doesn't even show up

2) The comment box loads but it doesn't get populated with comments

Here are my suggestions:

1) -- This is probably because you don't seem to have a 'data-width' attribute to your comment div. Try something like this:

```
var fbcomments = jQuery("<div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"http://example.com/comments\" data-numposts=\"5\" data-width=\"700\"></div>");
```

The problem here is that you're not setting any width to the comments therefore it has no dimensions to exist within. I'm sure if you load your page and inspect element, you will see that the comment box does, in fact, get appended but it just doens't get rendered. This is because it has no dimensions. For lack of a better description, it only exists as an 'idea' in the computer memory... it's a theoretical object. Theoretical objects need dimensions to get rendered. Also note that the 'data-width' in this case is in pixels. Feel free to change that number as you see fit. I went as far as to make them dynamically change the width to re-size to the current image width.

2) -- This is most likely because you don't have an ID set in your function for loading facebook comments. For information on how to get the proper ID in place please referance this video -- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNHfVdK8xik --. Basically, you have to go to the facebook developers page, create a new app there so that facebook can generate an ID number for you. Then you introduce that ID into your comment loading function like such:

```
(function(d, s, id) 
{
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=207663346095927";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}
    (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

In the code  above '207663346095927' is my specific ID. YOu would have to introduce the ID that facebook generated when you created your app.....

lol please don't use my ID lololol

Anyway, hope this helps. Good luck!